# Logout from FB Connected Website instead of Logout from Main FB Site

Tags: php, facebook

When I logged out Facebook from my web application, it automatically logout from the main Facebook site.  I have been looking for the solution almost 2 days and most of them are outdated and couldn't meet my needs.

If possible, I hope the solution can be run via PHP SDK library instead of JavaScript.

So far the code I found is shows as follows.

/* The getLogoutUrl() function from the FB-PHP-SDK help me to sign out all the Facebook related apps and the Facebook main site */
$fb_logout_url = $fb->getLogoutUrl();

Besides that, I have keep track on the COOKIES / SESSION that created after sign in from my web application, I have tried to clear the COOKIES or UNSET the SESSION, but it can't be remove.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Graph API for authenticate facebook and use fake facebook login button.

If login button pressed, your apps will check weather this person is logged in to facebook or not. If he/she logged in, it will generate access token to build communication within your apps to facebook

reference:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
```